# Google Script ~ How to automate authorization for app?

Tags: google-apps-script, automation, permissions, authorization

I've made an app in Google Apps Script to use in an iframe on my site.  Problem is I have to go through a bunch of steps every time someone new wants to use the app.

**My goal:**

What I would like to do is automate the app so it just approves anyone who authorizes it when they're initially prompted.  Given that the users initial confirmation is the important part, I don't see why it would be a problem to just have the app allow them in, without them having to wait for me to confirm their confirmation.

**The Breakdown:**

The permissions settings for the app are as follows:

```
"Execute the app as:" = "User accessing the web app"
"Who has access to the app:" = "Anyone"
```

The user must obviously have a Google account to use this app, and they have to authorize the app before they can use it.  When they do, an email gets sent to me, I have to find it, open it, and click the "Open sharing settings" link which opens the apps script file, then click "send" on the popup just to allow that one person to use the app.

Many people will be requesting authorization, and I don't want to have to check my gmail every day and manually confirm 5 or 10 new authorizations. That's way too much for me, and too much of a pain for the people using it.  Despite having put almost a year into coding this thing, I'd rather not deploy it than bother with that.  Yea, I definitely should've scoped this out better before coding the bulk of it.

**Potential Solution:**

This is a relatively naive guess, but would it work for me to make a second app that runs on a schedule, and opens the initial app's script file in an iframe, using `sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-popus"` attribute, then maybe use javascript to toggle "send" on the "share with others" pop-up?

Comment: You shouldn't need to share anything. Besides, why would you want to share the source code with the end-user?

Comment: The sharing settings is what grants the user permission to run the app.  The app runs as the user, and accesses their google drive, so they need to grant it permission.